# Problama al imprimir el resultado

Tags: c

Saludos estoy haciendo un programa en el que se tiene que introducir el resultado de la operación generara aleatoriamente de dos números también generados aleatoriamente. El problema es que al introducir un numero como respuesta el programa no imprime si esta correcta o si esta mal y se finaliza

Aquí el código:

```
 #include "stdio.h"  
 #include "time.h"  
 #include "stdlib.h"  
 #include "conio.h" 
 #include "math.h"  

int main()  
{  
    const char ops[] = "+-*";  
    int pregunta1,pregunta2,pregunta3,pregunta4,pregunta5;  
    int resultado1,resultado2,resultado3,resultado4,resultado5;  
    int respuesta1,respuesta2,respuesta3,respuesta4,respuesta5;  
    char operacion;  
    srand(time(NULL));  
    int numero1=rand()%100;
    int numero2=rand()%100;
    operacion = ops[rand( ) % sizeof( ops )];

    printf("1- Cual es el resultado de la siguiente operacion\n");
    printf( "%d %c %d\n", numero1, operacion, numero2 );
    scanf("%d",respuesta1);

    if(operacion<- '+'){
        resultado1 = numero1 + numero2;
        if(respuesta1=resultado1){
            printf("La respuesta es correcta");
        }
        else
            printf("La respuesta es incorrecta el resulatdo era: %d\n",resultado1);
    }
    if(operacion= '*'){
        resultado1 = numero1 * numero2;
        if(respuesta1=resultado1){
            printf("la respuesta es correcta\n");
        }
        else
            printf("La respuesta es incorrecta el resultado era: %d\n",resultado1);
    }
    if(operacion= '-'){
        resultado1 = numero1 - numero2;
        if(respuesta1=resultado1){
            printf("La respuesta es correcta\n");
        }
        else
            printf("La respuesta es incorrecta el resultado era: %d",resultado1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los condicionales if llevan ==. Ejemplo

```
 if(operacion== '+'){
        resultado1 = numero1 + numero2;
        if(respuesta1==resultado1){
            printf("La respuesta es correcta");
        }
        else
            printf("La respuesta es incorrecta el resulatdo era: %d\n",resultado1);
    }
```

Tambien probé tu código y al parecer el resultado no se guarda, pues te faltaba el & en el scanf

```
printf("1- Cual es el resultado de la siguiente operacion\n");
printf( "%d %c %d\n", numero1, operacion, numero2 );

 scanf("%d", &respuesta1);
```

Cambiando esa parte por el codigo anterior tu programa funcionó. Dale un vistazo y pruebalo.

Mira

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero te ayude. Un saludo.